# How can fix the warning errors present in the dependency array of the useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to resolve all warnings in my project but i don't know what dependencies should i include inside the dependency array. Below i share the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import { getPicture, getAlbums, updatePicture } from './ApiAdmin';

const UpdatePicture = ({ match }) => {

 ...

 const init = (pictureId) => {
    getPicture(pictureId).then(data => {
        if (data.err) {
            setValues({ ...values, err: data.err })
        } else {
            // populate the state
            setValues({
                ...values,
                name: data.name,
                album: data.album._id,
                formData: new FormData()
            })
            initAlbums()
        }
    })
 }

 const initAlbums = () => {
    getAlbums().then(data => {
        if (data.err) {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                error: data.err
            });
        } else {
            setValues({
                albums: data,
                formData: new FormData()
            });
         }
    });
 }

 const redirectUser = () => {
    if (redirectToProfile) {
        if (!error) {
            return < Redirect to="/" />
        }
     }
  }

 useEffect(() => {
    init(match.params.pictureId);
    redirectUser(); // allows display the changes when a picture is updated
 }, []);

...


}
```

And this is the warning that throws me:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'init', 'match.params.pictureId', and 'redirectUser'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I appreciate who can help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include them in your dependency array

```
useEffect(() => {
    init(match.params.pictureId);
    redirectUser(); // allows display the changes when a picture is updated
 }, [init, match.params.pictureId, redirectUser]);
```

These are all things that when they change should invoke a new run of useEffect. I recommend making `init` and `redirectUser` function use `useCallback` so they don't make it the `useEffect` run on each render unless they change (they will also have dependency arrays!).

Comment: Hello @Diesel, thanks for your time! But when i add the dependencies, in the terminal appear this error: Failed to compile.

  Line 32:9:   'init' is not defined          no-undef
  Line 32:15:  'match' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 32:39:  'redirectUser' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Forget it, with the useCallback I was able to resolve the warning. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the reactjs doc here. [Is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)